# Eigenvalues with transpose question.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am having trouble proving that a matrix A and its transpose $$A^T$$ have the same eigenvalues. I tried to use the formula $\det(I\lambda - A)$ but am getting nowhere. Is anyone able to help?

Comment: Hint: What is the determinant of the transpose of a matrix equal to?

Comment: The determinant of the original matrix?

Comment: That’s right, and $I\lambda$ is its own transpose, so...

Comment: Ah I see, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Arnaldo’s answer, below, uses these facts.

Answer (score 5):

Use that

$1.$ $\det X=\det X^T$ and

$2.$ $(X+Y)^T=X^T+Y^T$, so

$$\det(\lambda I-A)=\det(\lambda I-A)^T=\det(\lambda I^T-A^T)=\det(\lambda I-A^T)$$

Comment: @user435817: is it clear?

Comment: This is a good proof